# Instantiate class with context

Tags: c#, .net, oop, curly-braces

I have a simple class (that not inehited from IDisposable), that has some simple methods.

For access it, I do this:

```
var object= new class();
```

I saw in another code, one different way to instantiate:

```
var object= new class();
{

//do somenthing

}
```

what the curly braces do in this context ?

Comment: You're looking at an "Object initializer". You can read through the linked question for more info or just on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx

Comment: Your posted syntax for object initializer is bit wrong. It's `var object= new class()
{

//do somenthing

};`